# Adding columns to pandas not working with Django ORM

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am trying to add columns to existing pandas DataFrame. The added column gets data using Django ORM. My approaches are like the following:

1.

```
df['name'] = User.objects.get(id=df['id'])
```

2. 

```
df['name'] = df.assign(name=lambda x: User.objects.get(x.id))
```

But for both the approaches, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Field 'code' expected a number but got 0     1
1    18
Name: code, dtype: int64.
```

*The field is expecting a number but getting a pandas Series instead.*

How shall I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a *number* for the `id` field in `User.objects.get`, but `df['id']` returns a *pandas Series*

you can do something like:

```py
df = df.assign(name=[User.objects.get(x) for x in df['id']])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is giving error ```AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'code'```. I removed x.id and it is working. ```df = df.assign(name=[User.objects.get(x) for x in df['id']])```.  Please correct in answer.